# SQL Server Rebulid Index is not completely?

Tags: sql-server

I just have a question about rebuild index.

After I had rebuilt the index, I found the physical order of pages is not completely "in order", I saw the pages which has small PID's is after the page has big PID's, as below, the page 7234 is after 23596, this is why. Why is the PID after building the index not in order from small to big or from big to small?

```
objectID    PagePID PrePagePID  NextPagePID

93243387    23590   0       0       10  NULL
93243387    7440    23583   0       2   1
93243387    7441    0       0       2   2
93243387    23583   0       7440    2   1
93243387    23589   0       23591   1   0
93243387    23591   23589   23592   1   0
93243387    23592   23591   23593   1   0
93243387    23593   23592   23594   1   0
93243387    23594   23593   23595   1   0
93243387    23595   23594   23596   1   0
93243387    23596   23595   7432    1   0
93243387    7432    23596   7433    1   0    <---------
93243387    7433    7432    7434    1   0
93243387    7434    7433    7435    1   0
93243387    7435    7434    7436    1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following command just replace 'MyTable' with your tablename and verify if index is indeed fragmented.

```
SELECT DB_NAME(database_id) AS [Database Name]
   ,OBJECT_NAME(ps.OBJECT_ID) AS [Object Name]
   ,i.name AS [Index Name]
   ,ps.index_id
   ,ps.index_type_desc
   ,ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
   ,ps.fragment_count
   ,ps.page_count
   ,i.fill_factor
   ,i.has_filter
   ,i.filter_definition
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'LIMITED') AS ps
INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i WITH ( NOLOCK )
    ON ps.[object_id] = i.[object_id]
       AND ps.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
    AND OBJECT_NAME(ps.OBJECT_ID)  = 'MyTable'
ORDER BY avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
OPTION ( RECOMPILE );
```

after than reogranize all indexes on that table and after rebuild it.

Organize syntax

```
-- Reorganize all indexes on the HumanResources.Employee table.
ALTER INDEX ALL ON HumanResources.Employee
REORGANIZE ; 
GO
```

Rebuild syntax:

```
ALTER INDEX PK_Employee_BusinessEntityID ON HumanResources.Employee
REBUILD;
GO
```

after all that rerun the first query.